# How to export localization data in XLIFF format from a SwiftPM Package

Tags: ios, localization, xliff, swiftpm

I am developing an iOS application where most of the source code is in targets/modules within local SwiftPM package. This package is imported by a Xcode project that contains the app target.
I am trying to find a way to export all the localizable data in the standard XLIFF format. The option "Export Localizations" in the Xcode editor is not available for SwiftPM packages. When I generate a corresponding Xcode project with `swift package generate-xcodeproj` it does not contain any localization data, it seems a [bug](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650278), also the 'generate-xcodeproj' option as reported by the swift tool as: `"is no longer needed and will be deprecated soon"`.

Right now the only idea I have is to copy the localizations in a empty Xcode project and export them from there, is there any better way?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I build my own solution that I will open source soon to github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 14 has added support for exporting SwiftPM localizations, see the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes):

```
You can now export local Swift packages for localization. 
Xcode generates a single localizations catalog for all projects and Swift packages contained in a project or workspace. 
You can also use xcodebuild -importLocalizations and xcodebuild -exportLocalizations to export or import a Swift package. (56355281)
```